# Rates of reaction and the expansion of the universe

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, nucleosynthesis

In [Moore](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BVxXrgEACAAJ&dq=moore%202013%20relativity&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwislNeCiIDTAhUsCMAKHX8bBK0Q6AEIGjAA), 2013 the following statement is given about reaction rates and the expansion of the universe (my wording):

> For a reaction to occur we need a rate corresponding to at least one reaction per Hubble time i.e.
>   $$\Gamma \ge H$$

My question is: Is this an exact relation i.e. if $\Gamma \lt H$ no reaction occurs and if $\Gamma \ge H$ the reaction does occur or an approximate expression i.e. we can assume none occur if $\Gamma \ge H$. Either way please can you explain your answer.

Comment: It's never a strict limitation, we can always assume some reaction/process can happen, but when $\Gamma<H$ that probability is very close to zero in a large scale. Anyway that's how I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

On the average, if the time for something to happen is longer than the Hubble time the universe will have expanded before they can react, and they will be too far away from each other to react or influence each other.